# Perl Redis listen does not subscribe to channel

Tags: perl, redis, mojolicious

This code doesn't seem to be working and I don't know how to debug this.. I'm using Mojolicious to send out subscribed messages through websocket.

```
use Mojo::Redis;
#Controller
sub data_stream {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->inactivity_timeout(300);

    my $redis = Mojo::Redis-new('redis://xxxxxxxx@localhost:6379/');
    my $pubsub = $redis->pubsub;

    my $cb = $pubsub->listen('data' => sub  {
        my ($pubsub, $msg) = @_;
        $c->app->log->debug("WS: $msg");
        $c->send({text => $msg});
    });

    $c->on(finish => sub {
        $c->app->log->debug("WS CONNECTION CLOSED!");
        $pubsub->unlisten('data' => $cb)
    });
}
```

Sub above is called from the following router

```
$router->websocket('/data_stream')->to('grid#data_stream');
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code that sets up the websocket (from the usage of $c and $c->app I assume it's within a Mojolicious websocket route) and describe what's not working?

Comment: @Grinnz Thank you. I have editted my post. The code was based on the module example https://metacpan.org/source/JHTHORSEN/Mojo-Redis-3.11/examples/chat.pl, except the password in URI part.

And to verify if it's working or not, I have another script that is using Redis module. This script works works everytime I do publish directly from redis-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol this is the second question that I answered myself. 
This finally works when I moved the Mojo::Redis-new bit as helper

So in the router file;

```
$self->helper(redis => sub {
        state $redis = Mojo::Redis->new('redis://anything:jejakredis1234!@localhost:6379/');
    });
```

and in controller

```
sub data_stream {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->inactivity_timeout(300);

    my $pubsub = $c->redis->pubsub;

    my $cb = $pubsub->listen('data' => sub  {
        my ($pubsub, $msg) = @_;
        $c->app->log->debug("WS: $msg");
        $c->send({text => $msg});
    });

    $c->on(finish => sub {
        $c->app->log->debug("WS CONNECTION CLOSED!");
        $pubsub->unlisten('data' => $cb)
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem was likely that your Mojo::Redis object goes out of scope at the end of that action, which closes the connection. By declaring it as a state variable in a helper it stays around for the rest of that process.

Comment: @Grinnz Thank you! Yes I just noticed that as well. But how and when does it goes out of scope?

Comment: "my" variables go out of scope at the end of the block they are declared in if nothing else is holding a strong reference to them.

Comment: I see.. I thought when it reaches 'listen', the reference stays in that block